# How do I update my local repo without losing my already committed changes?

Tags: git, github

So I forked and cloned and created a new branch, made few changes and made a git commit.

However the original repo (upstream) had some new changes. I want to get them to my local repo and to be exact to the actual branch without losing my **already committed** changes. *I do have one commit right now*.

I looked for about an hour on how to do that, but it seems like a dead end without knowing the actual keywords that would get me a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `git pull --rebase` it will apply your commit over the new commit.

Comment: Thanks, say I am on branch X and want to do git pull --rebase from master branch of upstream, how would I make that happen?

Comment: You can do `git pull --rebase origin master`, read the manual about it here http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Answer (score 2):

You don't give informations about how you forked the code, but I think you did it through a hosting service (like GitHub).

Anyway the principle is the same:

- **Add** the main repository as a remote to be able to push and pull from it
- **Fetch** the latest modifications
- **Rebase** the modifications onto your work

---

How to do it in command line:

```
$ git remote add main http://url.git
$ git fetch main
$ git rebase main/master master
```

Comment: was edited by mistake but I think I restored the original content :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$ git checkout master # for your current repo
$ git remote add other http://url.git
$ git fetch other
$ git merge other/master # or whatever branch name is the branch you want.
```